# Detect difference between refresh and reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, reload

I have filled in a form containing my full name and address. When I hit ⌘R, the page refreshes, but the form is still containing the data I filled in.

When I reload the webpage via the reload button on the top left of Google Chrome, the form will be empty.

How can I detect this difference with JavaScript (or jQuery)?

---

I have tried this:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

     localStorage.setItem('gForm_isDone', '{"0":false,"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false,"11":false}');
     console.log('localStorage emptied');

     console.log(localStorage.getItem('gForm_isDone'));

});
```

In my scenario, I want to empty the localStorage, but only when the page reloads, not when it refreshes.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior (for me it's always cleared on chrome and never on FF), but can't you just check if the inputs have some value ?

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a good idea! I am really curious if there is another way (something that feels less like a workaround) to check it, but in this case it could work very well! Thanks for the valuable input! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `window.onbeforeunload` function to check if refresh/reload is pressed and handled the event `localStorage.clear()`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 var message = 'Are you sure you want to reload?';
  if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
    evt = window.event;
  }
  if (evt) {
    evt.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
}
```

Comment: it does not seem to work when the refresh button on the browser is clicked.

Comment: Did you test it, i just did and working as expected

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to detect the performance of the window using

```
if (window.performance) {
  console.info(performance.navigation.type); 
}
```

It will return `0` or `1`. `0` for page is not reloaded or called with empty cached. `1` will tell us that page is refreshed using `ctrl+R` or using browser button.

```
 if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window performance work on browser");
}
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded or just called with empty cache");
  }
```

Comment: But there is no difference between hard-refresh and simple refresh. (Though this comment may only apply for FF since I couldn't test on chrome : I can't repro OP's behavior)

Comment: hard-refresh will lead you to empty the cache and simple refresh usually wont.

Comment: It's quite nifty, it doesn't really check how you reloaded, only if the cache was emptied after the webpage loaded

Comment: I'm now testing it for browser compatibility, but it does feel a bit buggy

Comment: It doesn't even tell if the cache has been emptied (at least not on my FF) it only tells if we were coming from a different page.

Comment: You are right, Chrome handles it quite well, but on FF it doesn't work very well